# clicking logo on home page breaks navigation menu on mobile site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on this WordPress website: http://goo.gl/3VONrG

When I click on the logo on the mobile version of the site, it breaks the navigation menu and outputs all the HTML markup.

Logo link works fine on desktop version of site.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        <table class="fix-logo"><tr><td>
            <a href="http://www.example.com" class="logo"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/example_logo2.png" alt="Example Site" /></a>  
        </td></tr></table>
```

I have a feeling the problem is elsewhere, but unsure where to look.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try float:none in mobile display;

Comment: could you provide more code via jsfiddle?

Comment: There is so much code in this website, which files shall I provide?

Comment: looks like a problem with AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-ajax="false"` to your logo anchor tag.

```
<table class="fix-logo"><tr><td>
    <a href="http://www.example.com" class="logo" data-ajax="false"><img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/example_logo2.png" alt="Example Site" /></a>  
</td></tr></table>
```

Your AJAX loading function seems to break the page, I'd suggest looking into that code/function.

Comment: Works great. Was able to able this to some other site issues too. Much thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557940/login-popup-not-showing-on-mobile-site Any help on that is much appreciated.

Comment: Where do I find this AJAX loading function?

Comment: This file seems to be the culprit [mobile_script.js](http://www.alicejoeconsulting.com/wp-content/themes/jobengine/mobile/js/mobile_script.js)

Comment: How do I fix it? It's causing a lot of problems. Adding data-ajax="false" to the elements fixes those problems. But I can't add data-ajax="false" to the breadcrumbs since I cannot affect where the breadcrumbs are coded.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea. Maybe just disable this file? Comment it out and see if your site is still functional.

Comment: The child-theme my client had created is full of bugs. I'm just going to eliminate the features that don't work. Thank you for your continued help. :)