# Login Popup not Showing on Mobile Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Working on WordPress site: http://goo.gl/3VONrG

It has had a couple problems with Ajax, not sure if that relates to this.

Login pop-up works on desktop site but not on mobile site.

Here is the menu code for the button on the menu.

```
                    <li>
                        <a id="requestLogin" class="login-modal bg-btn-header btn-header" rel="modal-box" href="#login" title="<?php _e('Login', ET_DOMAIN);?>">
                            <span class="icon" data-icon="U" rel=""></span> 
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Found this code linked on the desktop site:

```
// View: Header
JobEngine.Views.Header = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'header',
    modal_login: {},
    modal_register: {},
    modal_forgot_pass: {},

    templates: {
        'login': '<li><a id="requestLogin" class="login-modal header-btn bg-btn-header" href="#login"><span class="icon" data-icon="U"></span></a></li>',
        'auth': _.templateSettings = {
            evaluate    : /<#([\s\S]+?)#>/g,
            interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
            escape      : /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g
        },
        'auth': _.template('<li><a href="{{ profile_url }}" class="bg-btn-header header-btn"><span class="icon" data-icon="U"></span></a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="' + et_globals.logoutURL + '" id="requestLogout" class="bg-btn-header header-btn"><span class="icon" data-icon="Q"></span></a></li>')
    },
    events: {
        'click a#requestLogout': 'doLogout',
        'click a#requestLogin': 'doLogin',
        'click a.requestlogin': 'doLogin',
        'click a#requestRegister': 'doRegister'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        if (!this.modal_login || !(this.modal_login instanceof JobEngine.Views.Modal_Login)) {
            this.modal_login = new JobEngine.Views.Modal_Login();
        }
        if (!this.modal_register || !(this.modal_register instanceof JobEngine.Views.Modal_Register)) {
            this.modal_register = new JobEngine.Views.Modal_Register();
        }
        if (!this.modal_forgot_pass || !(this.modal_forgot_pass instanceof JobEngine.Views.Modal_Forgot_Pass)) {
            this.modal_forgot_pass = new JobEngine.Views.Modal_Forgot_Pass();
        }
    },

    updateAuthButtons: function() {
        if (!JobEngine.app.currentUser.isNew()) {
            this.$('div.account ul').html(this.templates.auth(JobEngine.app.currentUser.attributes));
        } else {
            this.$('div.account ul').html(this.templates.login);
        }
        pubsub.trigger('afterUserChange', JobEngine.app.currentUser.isNew());
    },

    doLogout: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pubsub.trigger('je:request:logout');
        JobEngine.app.auth.doLogout();
    },

    doLogin: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pubsub.trigger('je:request:auth');

    },

    doRegister: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pubsub.trigger('je:request:register');
    }

});
```

How do I apply this code to the mobile site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was forgetting to add links to the required .js files in the header.

Comment: It is recommended to add JS links at the bottom of the page (before end of body `</body>`) instead of in `<head>` for better site loading.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to the bottom from now on. Won't let me accept answer yet, have to wait 24 hours.